# Python multiprocessing only working on one core with networking

Tags: python, networking, multiprocessing, tor

I am making a program to generate a .onion url and then test the url to see if it exists. The issue is I have set it up to use multiprocessing and it only uses one core, even when multiple processes are running.

My code is

```
import requests
import time
import sys
import threading
import random
import string
import multiprocessing

proxies = {
            'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150',
            'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'
        }

try:
    print("Your hidden ip is: " + requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/?", proxies=proxies, timeout=10).text)
    print("Checks at intervals to check if the commection is still established (pings google.com)")
except Exception as  e:
    print("Make sure tor is running or check that a socks proxy is running at 127.0.0.1:9150!")
    sys.exit(0)

def checkSite(site):
    if random.randint(0, 100) == 5:
        site = "https://google.com"
    try:
        data = requests.get(site, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
        if data.status_code == 200:
            print('Website exists {}'.format(site))
            sys.exit(0)
            print("hello")
        else:
            return
            #print('Website does not exist {}'.format(site))
    except Exception:
        #print('Website does not exist {}'.format(site))
        return

def genSite():
    site = ""
    x= string.ascii_lowercase + "234562"
    for i in range(0, 16):
            site = site + x[random.randint(0, len(x) - 1)]
    return ("http://" + site + ".onion")

def findSite():
    while True:
        checkSite(genSite())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    for _ in range(int(input("Enter number of processes: "))):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=findSite) # create a new Process
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

I have tried this with running a factorial function instead and this will utilize all cores, however it will only use one core when running the findSite function. I don't know weather this is an issue with networking and threads should be used or if my code is wrong. I have also tried to join the processes directly after they are started and put the join statement in different places however this has not worked.

Comment: the bottleneck of your program isn't CPU it's the network. multithreading would be enough. Don't hope to speed it up too much

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that one core is at 100% where as the others are at almost 0%. So I'm not to sure if it is networking and how the workload could be spread out if that is the case

Comment: why not loop on `process.join()` too BTW? are you sure you're not using `join` in the loop? that would be an error.

Comment: I changed the last function to ```if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    for _ in range(int(input("Enter number of threads: "))):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=findSite) # create a new Process
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
``` Is that what you meant?